# Updating an NSUserDefaults value monthly

Tags: ios, swift2

I'm new to iOS Development using Swift 2.1 and I'd like to know if it's possible to fire an event daily/monthly/yearly

Is it possible? I've learnt that whenever an app is released from memory it's not possible to do anything with it.

I've also read that I can store the last time the user ran the app as a NSUserDefaults value and compare it to the time when he run it again

I've came across this [link](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/system/how-to-run-code-at-a-specific-time) which runs a code at a specific time, not sure if it works with date too or not

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to "fire" an event whenever you please if your app isn't running, but you can certainly check your app's condition each time it's launched and check to see whether enough time has passed to do the work you want. In your app delegate's `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions()` method, look in `NSUserDefaults` to see the last-saved date, and, if more than a month has passed, take whatever action you want.

Note: if you weren't aware, you can read and write `NSDate` objects right into `NSUserDefaults` with no conversion needed. Some example code to help you get started:

```
let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

if let previousDate = defaults.objectForKey("LastSavedDate") as? NSDate {
    // compare the last-saved date to now; how much time has passed?
    let timePassed = previousDate.timeIntervalSinceNow;
} else {
    // no previously saved date; presumably take your action immediately?
}

defaults.setObject(NSDate(), forKey: "LastSavedDate")
```

Comment: Thanks TwoStraws for your help and info! +1